# convert nested array of object to simple Json object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

hi need some help regarding normalizing array of objects.
i have this nested array which has some json objects and those objects have array.

```
  [
   {
    customerId: 20
    customerName: "customer 1"
    orderItems: [
       {
        productId: '23'
        productName: 'ice cream'
        price: '200'
        },
      ....
     ] 
   },
    customerId: 21
    customerName: "customer 2"
    orderItems: [
       {
        productId: '47'
        productName: 'bottle'
        price: '60'
        },
       {
        productId: '48'
        productName: 'shake'
        price: '544'
        },
       ....
     ] 
   },
 ]
```

i want it like this

```
    [
     {
        customerId: 20
        customerName: "customer 1",
        productId: '23'
        productName: 'ice creems'
        price: '200',
        ....
     },
      {
        customerId: 21
        customerName: "customer 2",
        productId: '47'
        productName: 'bottle'
        price: '60',
        ....
      },
       {
        customerId: 21
        customerName: "customer 2",
        productId: '48'
        productName: 'shake'
        price: '544',
        ....
       }
     ]
```

Can someone help me in this regard? i have tried map operator but i couldn't loop through inner array.
thanks

Comment: "map operator but i couldn't loop through inner array"... can you show the map operator you have tried?

Comment: array?.map((record, index) => ({

  customerId: record?.customerId,
  customerName: record?.customerName,
  productId: record?.orderItems[index]?.productId,
  productName: record?.orderItems[index]?.productName,
  price: record?.orderItems[index]?.price,
}));

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) approach and take the denormalized data.

```js
var data = [{ customerId: 20, customerName: "customer 1", orderItems: [{ productId: '23', productName: 'ice cream', price: '200' }] }, { customerId: 21, customerName: "customer 2", orderItems: [{ productId: '47', productName: 'bottle', price: '60' }, { productId: '48', productName: 'shake', price: '544' }] }],
     denormalized = data.flatMap(({ orderItems, ...customer }) =>
         orderItems.map(order => ({ ...customer, ...order })));

console.log(denormalized);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` and `.flat()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [{
  customerId: 20,
  customerName: "customer 1",
  orderItems: [{
    productId: '23',
    productName: 'ice cream',
    price: '200'
  }] 
}, {
  customerId: 21,
  customerName: "customer 2",
  orderItems: [{
    productId: '47',
    productName: 'bottle',
    price: '60'
  }, {
    productId: '48',
    productName: 'shake',
    price: '544'
  }]
}];
 
const result = data.map(
  ({orderItems, ...rest}) => orderItems.map(o => Object.assign({}, rest, o))
).flat();
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```